# XSL check immediate preceding sibling

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having a huge brain fart over the last two days. I need to check if the first `<step1>` child element of `<proc>` has a preceding sibling of `<note>`:

```
<proc>
   <note>
       <trim.para>Some sort of note</trim.para>
   </note>
   <step1>
       <para>Turn off all electrical power .</para>
   </step1>
   <step1>
       <para>A second step.</para>
   </step1>
</proc>
```

I am trying to transform `<step1>` element (and child `<step2>` elements) to `<proceduralStep>` elements with the following XSL and not having any luck in getting the `<note>` to be included:

```
<xsl:template match="step1 | step2">
        <!-- create key/value pair to store existing ids with new value for proceduralStep element-->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@id">
                <proceduralStep id="{@id}">
                    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][note]">
                        <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::*[1][note]">
                            <note>
                                <notePara>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./trim.para"/>
                                </notePara>
                            </note>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </proceduralStep>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <proceduralStep>
                    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][note]">
                        <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::*[1][note]">
                            <note>
                                <notePara>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="./trim.para"/>
                                </notePara>
                            </note>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </proceduralStep>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

This outputs:

```
<mainProcedure>
    <proceduralStep>
      <para>Turn off all electrical power.</para>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep>
      <para>A second step.</para>
    </proceduralStep>
</mainProcedure>
```

I need this to output:

```
<mainProcedure>
    <proceduralStep>
        <note>
            <notePara>Some sort of note</notePara>
        </note>
       <para>Turn off all electrical power.</para>
    </proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep>
      <para>A second step.</para>
    </proceduralStep>
</mainProcedure>
```

I already have a template in place that handles `<note>` elements when they occur inside of the `<step1>` or `<step2>` elements (or anywhere else). I have created an empty template to prohibit the proc\note from being placed in my output:

```
<xsl:template match="note[parent::proc]"></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
    <note>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </note>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note/trim.para">
    <notePara>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </notePara>
</xsl:template>
```

I swear I have done this before but I am just not recalling it this morning (or yesterday morning for that matter).

Comment: Does using `preceding-sibling::*[1][self::note]` instead of `preceding-sibling::*[1][note]` solve the problem? That change would implement the verbal description "need to check if the first <step1> child element of <proc> has a (immediately) preceding sibling of <note>".

Comment: That did it. I knew it was something I had seen/done before, just in a different context. I use this for another template, just for following-sibling. Thank you @MartinHonnen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin suggests in his comment, you need to use the `self::` axis to check the preceding sibling.  You can also get rid of the `if`, and significantly reduce the code duplication here by copying the existing `id` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="step1 | step2">
    <!-- create key/value pair to store existing ids with new value for proceduralStep
         element-->
    <proceduralStep>
        <!-- copy id attribute from step1|step2 if it exists, do nothing if not -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="@id" />
        <!-- no need for an if here - if the immediately preceding sibling is not a
             note then the select will return an empty node set, which makes the
             for-each a no-op -->
        <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::note]">
            <note>
                <notePara>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./trim.para"/>
                </notePara>
            </note>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </proceduralStep>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out how i can simplify my code, will be changing this as well.